# Finding and removing vowels in a word: my program does not deliver the consonants

Tags: python, python-3.5

here is my program

```
    import time
    print('hello, i am the consonants finder and i am going to find he consonants in your word')
    consonants = 'b'  'c' 'd' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z'
    word = input('what is your word: ').lower()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('here is your word/s only in consonants')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Calculating')
    time.sleep(1)

    for i in word:
        if i == consonants:
            print((i), ' is a consonant')
```

here Is the output:

```
hello, i am the consonants finder and i am going to find he consonants in your word
what is your word: hello
here is your word/s only in consonants
Calculating
        #No output
```

how come the output does not give the consonants

this is what the output should be:

```
 hello, i am the consonants finder and i am going to find he consonants in your word
what is your word: hello
here is your word/s only in consonants
Calculating
hll
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with list comprehension:

```
print ''.join([c for c in word if c in consonants])
```

Althought this would remove all points, colons, commas,... also won't consider the accented letters.

I'd rather remove the vowels:

```
word = "hello again, consider CAPS"
vocals = 'aeiou'
print ''.join([c for c in word if c.lower() not in vocals])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep

CONSONANTS = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz')

print('hello, i am the consonants finder and i am going to find the consonants in your word')

word = input('what is your word: ').lower()
sleep(1)

print('Here is your word/s only in consonants:')
print("".join(ch for ch in word if ch in CONSONANTS))
```

Your mistakes:

```
consonants = 'b'  'c' 'd'    # ?
```

When you have run-together strings like this, Python combines them into a single string; so you effectively wrote `consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'` (a single string).

Then

```
if i == consonants:
```

`i` is a single character, `consonants` is all consonants; they will **never** match. Thus, you get **no** characters!

You could replace this with `if i in consonants:` and it would work; but making consonants a set will be faster. (`ch in str` has to scan through the string, one character at a time; `ch in set` does just one operation).

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
for i in word:
if i in consonants:
    print(i,end="")
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, but can you please explain what ,end means as I have never encountered this before, I am a beginner programmer

Comment: A print call is ended by a newline, to change this behaviour, you can assign an arbitrary string to the keyword parameter "end". If you use just print(i) you'll get every character at a new line. [see more details here](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
print('hello, i am the consonants finder and i am going to find he consonants in your word')
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
word = input('what is your word: ').lower()
time.sleep(1)
print('here is your word/s only in consonants')
time.sleep(1)
print('Calculating')
time.sleep(1)

for i in word:
    if i in consonants:
        print((i), ' is a consonant')
```

Just like you did the "i in word" part do the consonant part in the same way. 
Think of the consonant variable as a string that contains all the consonants. So now you are just checking whether each alphabet in the word is contained in the consonant variable(which is a string containing all the consonants) or not.

Otherwise, what you were doing wrong is correctly pointed out by **Hugh Bothwell**

Cheers!!!